# Drupal to Wordpress Migration - Can we keep/recreate our forms?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, webform-civicrm

As our tiny organization only has me as our volunteer web developer (and I am far from an expert) we think it may be prudent to migrate over to Wordpress, where things are a little less technically difficult so others will be able to lend a hand. My only hesitation is that we currently make havy use of Drupal's Webform CiviCRM Integration module. We use it for memberships, for event signups, and to collect payment on both of those items. Does Wordpress have comparable capabilities, or would we be leaving that behind?

Comment: possibly. The last answer there is from 2015, and ran generally along the lines of "it's in development, maybe." Hopefully the answer has changed since then?

Comment: I actually added a new answer when I posted this yesterday, which is that there's another option.  That said - it's nowhere near the level of functional that Webform-CiviCRM is.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no - but having said that we do have one organization that went with a Wordpress main site for content delivery [example.org] and a second Drupal/CiviCRM site [secure.example.org] - to leverage all that Drupal can do. So the Drupal component on the second site is very small - mostly for webform_civicrm; views displays. One added benefit is that donors really like going to the 'secure' site.